# pandas merging dataframes with string vars; works for most obs but not others despite exact matching

Tags: string, pandas, merge, series

I am trying to merge dataframes in Pandas on two variables; most merge, but about 10% do not merge.

I have tried converting the series to strings. I have tried merging the frames as series. Seems to be no difference.

I am loading with pd.ExcelFile

```
f1 = pd.ExcelFile(file 1.xlsx)
f1 = f1.parse('data') 
f2 = pd.ExcelFile(file 2.xlsx)
f2 = f2.parse('data') 

g = pd.merge(f1,f2,on=['File Name','Stock'],how='left')

data looks like:
File Name: 965_abcd_10022019.pdf; Stock: Stock A
File Name: abcded10022019; Stock: Stock B
```

I expect all to merge on exact matches. I've checked in excel, etc. Been checking equivalency of strings for a while. Visually appear perfectly matched. But about 10% don't merge.

Comment: Have you tried stripping whitespaces?  i.e. `f1['File Name'] = f1['File Name'].str.strip()`

Comment: I did but now see it has remained a pandas series and not a string. I used apply map and various ways.